# Remove operation in c# linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list

I have a problem concerning c# remove operation in linked list. `LinkedListNode<T>` is immutable, but `Remove(LinkedListNode<T>)` is constant time. Why do I have a problem with it? Here is the reason:

Normally, when removing I would write the following code (forget about nulls):

```
public void Remove(LinkedListNode<T> node) 
{
    node.Previous.Next = node.Next;
    node.Next.Previous = node.Previous;
}
```

But since `LinkedListNode<T>` is immutable, this is not an option. How is it done in O(1) time then?

Comment: Why not use [`LinkedList<T>.Remove()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwsxykxy(v=vs.110).aspx)? I assume the `LinkedListNode<T>` you're referring to is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahf4c754(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Well, it doesn't. This class provides only getters for Previous and Next.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I don't have a problem with usage. I know I can. My question is different - as I wrote - how does it work in O(1) time?

Comment: Ah, OK. I would guess that they're just doing something sneaky in the implementation to update the private fields. Pretty sure the source code for all this stuff is available now.

Comment: Yes, Gilad Green had that in an update before I was done typing my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't immutable but those properties are `read-only` properties:

```
//Out of LinkListNode<T>:

public LinkedListNode<T> Next {
    get { return next == null || next == list.head? null: next;} //No setters
}

public LinkedListNode<T> Previous {
    get { return prev == null || this == list.head? null: prev;} //No setters
}
```

That is why you can't assign them.
Instead of implementing it yourself use `LinkedList<T>.Remove()` method:

```
LinkedList<int> list = new LinkedList<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
list.Remove(3);

// list: 1,2,4
```

If you look under [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs,df5a6c7b6b60da4f) you will see the implementation as:'

```
public bool Remove(T value) {
    LinkedListNode<T> node = Find(value);
    if (node != null) {
        InternalRemoveNode(node);     //  <==============
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void Remove(LinkedListNode<T> node) {
    ValidateNode(node);          
    InternalRemoveNode(node);         //  <==============
}

internal void InternalRemoveNode(LinkedListNode<T> node) {
    Debug.Assert( node.list == this, "Deleting the node from another list!");   
    Debug.Assert( head != null, "This method shouldn't be called on empty list!");
    if ( node.next == node) {
        Debug.Assert(count == 1 && head == node, "this should only be true for a list with only one node");
        head  = null;
    } 
    else {
    /******************** Relevant part here *****************/
        node.next.prev = node.prev;
        node.prev.next = node.next;
        if ( head == node) {
            head = node.next;
        }
    }
    node.Invalidate();  
    count--;
    version++;          
}
```

So basically they implemented it as you wanted too but they can use different variables which are `internal` and are not `read-only`:

```
internal LinkedListNode<T> next;
internal LinkedListNode<T> prev;
```

Comment: @sm21 - check my latest update - I've added the code that .Net uses

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the method Remove of LinkedList(T) relies on:

```
internal void InternalRemoveNode(LinkedListNode<T> node)
```

which itself, in turn, directly manipulates the corresponding backing fields of LinkedListNode(T), both declared with the [internal visibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) as well :

```
internal LinkedListNode<T> prev;
```

and

```
internal LinkedListNode<T> next;
```

'Hope this helps,